# Streaming audio using AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, audio, flash-cs5

I have a simple as3 audio player. Works great for streaming a mp3 local file or for streaming regular ip radio, but fail when I try streaming from a ip address with mpeg encoding.
Is a encoding problem? There is a solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean exactly when you say you are streaming from an IP? How does you audio player get the file from the remote computer? It might just be a problem of accessing the file.

(Sorry for not just commenting, I don't have enough reputation yet.)

Comment: I'm streaming from a remote server but i've permissions to handle data across domains.